# Populating Worksheet with dataframe values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have `xlsx` file `test.xlsx` with multiple worksheets, I read in the file in `pandas` as `dataframe`. Then after further processing I would like to do `vlookup` in sheet called main by looking into sheet named third.

I am trying to use the merge method for `vlookup` in pandas but it is not working. `vlookup` should return entries in main sheet for range B2:F6.

This is how the main sheet should like after `vlookup` is done:

[image]

And this is the third sheet where data is looked into:

[image: Third sheet]

```
df4=pd.merge(df3[['TM Cell ID','Cluster','BCQA (F)','Activation (F)','Tech BIS (A)','Technology Required','Modernisation Priority']],df2, on=['TM Cell ID'],right_index=False)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
        
df4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='main', header=None, index=False,startcol=1, startrow=2)
    
writer.save()
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: what is in df2? Is it just the relevant "TM Cell ID" that should appear in 'Main' for the vlookup? If so, I believe you need to add `how='right'` as an option in your merge. pandas defaults to a left merge which will keep everything in df3 assuming I have your data structure correct.